# Apache 2.4 require all not working

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, virtualhost

My virtual host configuation file contains the following (Apache version is 2.4.7):

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    [...]
    <Directory [...]>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I want to access the directory the server returns a 403 error and the apache logs contain

```
[access_compat:error] [pid 3433] [client [...]] AH01797: client denied by server configuration
```

And if I swap "Require all granted" with

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

the line it the log file changes to

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 4970] [client [...]] AH01630: client denied by server configuration
```

How can I further investigate what is going wrong? And why is authz_core active when using the old directives and access_compat when using the new ones?

EDIT:
Output of apachectl -M: http://pastebin.com/YxvNtAZr

Comment: What does apachectl -M give you?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Try removing the `access_compat` module, while using the correct `Require all granted` directive

Comment: I already tried this, but unfortunately the php5 module from the Ubuntu Server 14.04 Repos (update is not possible) still uses the old syntax. (edit: typo)

Comment: All you have to do is edit the `<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">` and `<FilesMatch  "^\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml|ps)$">` blocks in the `php5.conf` file to delete the `Order Deny,Allow` and `Deny from all` directives, replacing them with `Require all denied`. The Apache documentation warns repeatedly against mixing old and new access control directives, stating that "unpredictable results" will happen.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was another part, but now I can disable access_compat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem ... there was a enabled config file which overwrote the access rules for this particular directory.